# Could AI create a more complex language and (if so) how?

Tags: evolution, language, computers

Animals use less intelligent language, so one may assume that human language is unintelligent to extraterrestrial life. We use technology to perceive senses that we do not naturally have (e.g., seeing X-rays or hearing <20Hz). Does this mean that one could use AI to map out a "language evolution" and use it to communicate in ways that we normally can't (just like using technology to see or hear)? I'm not talking so much about echolocation; I refer to a "natural progression" from syntax, semantics, pragmatics, etc. into "evolved" speech.

**Edit:** For clarity, what I specifically ask about is this: animals (e.g., chimpanzees, bonobos, and dolphins) understand phonology and morphology but not (due to limited brain capacity) complex syntax. This is seen in the infamous case of a monkey who could not distinguish between sentences, "Sue loves Sam" and "Sam loves Sue." Therefore, language (to them) is phonology, morphology, and very basic syntax. To us, language is complex phonology, morphology, syntax, semantics, pragmatics, etc. We think that this is a "peak evolution" of language, but for all we know we could be like monkeys who do not know the possibilities. With an AI that has unlimited cognition, could we find a way to run algorithms that could help AI to accidentally stumble upon a natural progression (i.e., into a sub-field of language that we did not previously know of)?

Comment: This already happening (sort of): [Facebook put cork in chatbots that created a secret language](https://www.cnet.com/news/what-happens-when-ai-bots-invent-their-own-language/)

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Worldbuilding RoCo. Unfortunately I am not sure this is a WorldBuilding question or a question about the current state of AI. Can you please clarify what you are referring to when you use the term AI? In the real world sense, they are simply algorithms that are great at detecting and emulating patterns, in a Sci-Fi sense, they can be super intelligent and all knowing.

Comment: @Shadowzee This is definitely a world-building question since I don't think that the context would be appreciated in a more scientific part of the StackExchange community, but I am also looking for a realistic answer.

Comment: @RoCo Just because it wouldn't fit in with the forum rules elsewhere please don't assume you can post it here without regard for our rules. I suggest you study the [help] in more detail specifically regarding the rules about how to [ask], then re-read the comments. We have very well trained scientists of wide and varied specialties here, and have rigorous requirements. Please re-read our definition of [off-topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: *could we find a way to run algorithms that could help AI to accidentally stumble upon a natural progression*  We can't define what a fictitious AI might be able to do with unknown algorithms. This strikes me as not even being world building - it's speculation inviting discussion, and discussion is off topic here.

Comment: *"Animals use less intelligent language, so one may assume that human language is unintelligent to extraterrestrial life"* This is a textbook *non sequitur*.

Comment: To @Renan's point, I do believe Jane Goodall considers the language of the primates to be quite intelligent indeed.

Comment: What does "complex syntax" mean? Why do you believe that English syntax is "complex"? It is most certainly much less complicated than the syntax of other well-known languages, such as Greek or German or Latin. And I am not at all sure that you understand what "morphology" is; most certainly the various vocalizations of chimpanzees do not have anything similar to human language morphology. And the phrase "intelligent language" is utterly meaningless; languages do not participate to the category "intelligence".

Comment: What I mean is that human language has the ability to have complex syntax; I'm not saying that English syntax is complex. I'm trying to give chimpanzees credit where credit is due; I don't want to portray them as completely inept because they do have at least a bit of morphology. I would also say that human language is more complex and therefore more "intelligent" (requiring more brainpower than most animals have in that department) than animals'.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by 'complex'. If by 'complex' you mean 'difficult to talk with', than Navajo is the current winner and it's very easy to create a language unpronounceable by humans. If you mean 'ability to specify things with precision', then American English is moving towards that at a pretty rapid clip, seeing as the language is constantly updated when new concepts are discovered and a lot of other languages will borrow the English words for them (although frequently the English words that are used aren't English in origin, so ... *shrugs* make of that what you will). A computer can expedite the process, but making a new language from scratch is unnecessary.

If by 'complex' you mean 'a language beyond the singularity that approaches language with a brand new paradigm to the point where it's a third-dimensional cube where all other languages are two dimensional square', then the answer is 'no.' If humans can't envision it, programs written by humans can't either.

Answer to your edit: I can't prove that a sub-field of the language exists which we would natural progress to such that a computer algorithm  could fine it *doesn't exist* because negatives can't be proven - but that's just conjecture.